# Updating controller from iPhone to iPad with size classes?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout, size-classes

I have been using autolayout and constraints to make my app look pretty on every iPhone, and it looks ok so far. I am having problem with iPad. I have a screen that when viewed on iPad has to much blank space.

I would like to use bigger images, and larger font. Maybe add one more label. Can I do this with sizeclasses, or i have to do it some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do all that with size classes – and indeed they are the preferred solution for this, because you automatically get support for slide over and split view.

If you're using Interface Builder (which, quite frankly, is by far the best way to work with size classes), you'll see little + buttons next to many configuration option of your user interface. For example, you mentioned larger font: right there to the left of the font options is a + symbol, and clicking it lets you add a different font size for specific size classes.

I made an app a few months ago that worked on all iPhones and iPads as well as Apple TV, all using the same base storyboard with customisations using size classes. There's such a big gap between the tiny iPhone 4s and the massive iPad Pro that size classes were basically essential. And yes, split view worked flawlessly out of the box, which was a bonus.

**My primary advice:** Design for your smallest screen first, then add size classes to configure the largest options. You can then choose some views to either not be installed (it's a checkbox) or just be sized down very small to make sure your UI looks and works great in its most challenging environment. If you can do that, making iPad work is a cinch because it feels like you have acres of space ;)

**Another useful tip that enough people know about:** Enable the assistant editor, then choose Preview mode for your storyboard. This lets you see how your layouts look on multiple different devices and orientations simultaneously, as you work. If you're looking to make best use of size classes (and the massive difference in space between iPhone and iPad) using the previewer is essential.

Comment: I use interface builder and storyboards... I see how it is for fonts, but how about putting bigger images. For example on iPhone imageView is 30x30, but on iPad i want it to be 50x50. So on iPhone i would set one image with size 30x30, but on iPad how would i set bigger image. On imageView there is no +.

Comment: If you are specifying exact widths and heights, then what you should do is click the bottom of your storyboard window where it says "w Any h Any" and choose which size class you want to target. The bar will turn blue to show that you have an active size class, and any changes you make should apply only to that size class. So what you can do is say "I want an exact size of 50x50 for this image view, but in Compact Width Any Height (i.e., iPhones in portrait or landscape) I want an exact size of 30x30."